# Getting default date format in the console when working with excel

Tags: java, excel, date

I am using excel to get the data in java.
I have given some date as yyyy-mm-dd.
But when I am trying to get those values in the console using System.out.println(date).
I am getting different date format as dd-mmm-yyyy.
Whatever the date format I have given,in the console its printing only the dd-mmm-yyyy format.Any suggestion plz..

Comment: "I am using excel to get the data in java" -> What? Do you mean "I am using Java to get the data in Excel"?

Comment: And without the code, impossible to help!

Comment: Yeah ..I am using java code to load the data from excel @AKSW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `Date` object in `System.out.println`, it will call `toString()` method of `Date` class and print the date in `dd-mmm-yyyy` format (with time as well).

If you want to print `Date` in any custom format then you need to use `SimpleDateFormat`, e.g.:

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
System.out.println(format.format(date));
```

[Here's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) the javadoc for `SimpleDateFormat` class.

Comment: thats ok.Can't we do anything using excel?

Comment: We don't need to. If we are concerned about printing the date then this is the ideal way. With excel, you are probably using `POI` or equivalent library to read the date and I would not recommend messing with input data just for the sake of output format.